# Kruskal-Wallis Test - medians are same but result is significant?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, median, kruskal-wallis-test

I have run a Kruskal Wallis test in my dataset and have a significant overall result (p<<0.001). However, since the medians for my categories are the same, I can't work out the direction of the trends. Post hoc tests have revealed which groups are different, but I'm not sure how to work which groups are affected more by my treatments than the others - is there any way to work this out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not plot the data to see? Also, if medians are the same, look at other measures of level such as means or geometric means, even though they are not linked to Kruskal-Wallis.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but you don't just look at medians for this purpose when they differ either: Kruskal-Wallis *does not test medians*. Even if the medians were different, looking at the medians to work out what directions the differences are in is dangerous because the difference in medians might be in the opposite direction to the thing that the Kruskal-Wallis is seeing. While they're not easy to interpret, the mean ranks will differ in the 'correct' direction. However, that on its own doesn't tell you which groups are "different".

Comment: @NickCox , my data is very skewed, so it's hard to tell what's happening, but looking at means was a helpful suggestion, thank you!

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your tip about the mean ranks, that should be easy to plot and then explain the direction of effects. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what the outcome variable Y measures?